# Mention of open source license in product

Tags: open-source-software, attribution

We have a product that heavily relies on open source licenses like Apache 2.0, GPL etc.

Our product is a service that we host inhouse and our customers use (like Basecamp), like a Saas, so nobody would ever get the source code.

I know I have to include license notice of the used framework, but where exactly do include this notice? Do I put a special page IN the product? Should I include it in sales agreements? Or maybe just on a section on our product website?

Comment: Quick question: Is the software purely a SaaS? Just to make sure, there is no binary/executable ever being distributed to end users, right? Also, is the AGPL license ever used as part of your array of open source libraries?

Comment: You can compare it with Basecamp, there is a service online, hosted by us, and that's it. But actually, some customers have a small integration piece living on their server (binary) that does use some Microsoft packages.

Comment: Alright. So I can assume that there's no AGPL here, right?

Comment: No the only licenses we use are: Apache 2.0, BSD, MIT, MS, MS-PL.

Answer (score -2):

What do you mean with "nobody would ever get the source code". If GPL is used it *contaminates* the product and further distributions of the product must be accompanied with the entire source code.

Comment: please feel free Zizouz212

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: you just said: nope. and saying nope is not really an explanatory answer.

Comment: It's doesn't "contaminate" anything. The OP said that the software will be used as a service, so nothing is technically distributed. Therefore, this answer as wrong. Have you read up the license? You may be confusing yourself with the AGPL.

Comment: Does the GPL require that source code of modified versions be posted to the public? The GPL does not require you to release your modified version, or any part of it. You are free to make modifications and use them privately, without ever releasing them. 

But if you release the modified version to the public in some way, the GPL requires you to make the modified source code available to the program's users, under the GPL.

Thus, the GPL gives permission to release the modified program in certain ways, and not in other ways; but the decision of whether to release it is up to you.

Comment: this was taken from GNU FAQs

Comment: But some way does not include being used as "Software as a Service." That's the purpose of the AGPL, not the GPL.

Comment: some way means exactly "some way". unless it falls under one exception of GPL (e.g. see version 2). source code must be made available.

Comment: Regardless, the answer isn't clear, it's not the best of quality, and you don't present very convincing arguments here. My down vote still remains.

Comment: :) i'm not here to fight about votes

Comment: i don't see this forum as a contest, but rather as a Knowledge pool! my understanding is that generally, GPLed code use forces the disclosure of all source code - original and modified. you're first argument against this understanding was: "nope".

Comment: @Zizouz212, you keep insisting on AGPL - even when the question does not mention it. And even if did no relevant difference would apply. AGPL provides the same restrictions and freedoms as the GPLv3 with one difference: that source code must be distributed along with web publication. Basically: AGPL is the GPL of the web - no difference wrt source code disclosure.

Comment: I appreciate the intent of your Answer, but it is not well explained or documented.